# Add variable to json string in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to call graph api, need some help to check on this

```
string addItemJsonString = "{\"fields\":{\"ID\":\"" + ID + "\",\"DeviceName\":\"" + deviceName + "'}\"}";
```

This is my json, i need to convert them into a string

```
{
   "fields":{
      "ID": ID,
      "Device Name": deviceName
   }
}
```

Graph API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. You said "But when i print out orgChartData" but your code doesn't do that.

Comment: With [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) you can do this with the following single line: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { fields = new { ID, = ID,  DeviceName = deviceName}})` . Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough. But if I understand you correctly you want to convert this json

```
{
   "fields":{
      "ID": ID,
      "Device Name": deviceName
   }
}
```

into string.

I strongly suggest you use serialization libraries and do not write json yourself. You can easily create a class or dictionary and serialize it to that json.

But if you insist you have two errors in your json string.

1- After deviceName, you used `'` instead of `"`.

2- You add extra `"` before last `}`.

So the correct json should be something like this

```
string addItemJsonString = "{\"fields\":{\"ID\":\"" + ID + "\",\"DeviceName\":\"" + deviceName + "\"}}";
```

Answer (score 4):

Use interpolation

```
$"{{\"fields\":{{\"ID\":\"{ID}\",\"DeviceName\":\"{deviceName}\"}}}}";
```

But much better to create a DTO class and serialize it into JSON.

```
public class MyDto
{
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public FieldDto Fields { get; set; }
}

public class FieldDto
{
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Device name")]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
}

public static Main(string[] args)
{
    int id = 1;
    string deviceName = "Phone";

    var blee = new MyDto
    {
        Fields = new FieldDto
        {
            Id = id,
            DeviceName = deviceName
        }
    }

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blee);
}
```

For serialization use Newtonsoft library
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonConverters.htm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are asking about formating json in C#.

1. With `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer and **anonymous objects** (convinient and recomended since more universal and less error prone)

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var obj = new { fields = new { ID = ID, DeviceName = deviceName } };
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

2. Direct string manipulation (you need to handle json formating yourself!). E.g. strings must be encapsulated in double quot always, and you need make sure  they are escaped if it exists within its value

```cs
Debug.Assert(!ID.Contains('"'));
Debug.Assert(!deviceName.Contains('"'));
string addItemJsonString = $"{{\"fields\":{{\"ID\":\"{ID}\",\"DeviceName\":\"{deviceName}\"}}\"}}";
```